# Flask Login Sessions Not Working

Tags: flask, flask-login

I'm having an issue with **Flask-Login** where for some reason it seems to clear the data from my session. This issue only seem to happen to me when I run my application on **AWS** within a Docker container. There doesn't seem to be any issues when this is run locally within a Docker container. The container kick starts the application using **supervisord** to launch the **nginx** and **gunicorn** servers.

I'm using Flask-Login and SQLAlchemy to handle my user logins. I'm creating a custom token using the `get_auth_token()` method in my User model which stores the token with some session data in my database. I use the `token_loader` and `user_loader` callbacks to retrieve my User data from the database which works fine.

However, if I'm not actively using my application for a few minutes the session data seems to disappear when I change to a page that requires a login. My session cookie remains unchanged and my `token_loader` or `user_loader` callbacks never seem to be called. To work out what might be happening with the session I attached a `@app.before_request` handler to print the session contents:

```
[2015-09-29 14:47:21,348] DEBUG in __init__: <SecureCookieSession {u'csrf_token': '51b5b253c55ac954c1bc61dd2dca513e18c4d790', u'_fresh': True, u'user_id': 3, u'_id': 'd3adbd2ed3905986d515aeb04cd1ff7d'}>
[2015-09-29 14:47:21,382] DEBUG in __init__: <SecureCookieSession {u'_flashes': [('message', u'Please log in to access this page.')]}>
```

It appeared that all of the user information was there for me to be able to load my user but it has bailed out and re-directed to the login page with the Flask-Login flash error. This re-directs before it even touches my callbacks to load the user from the database.

Is this possibly just a set up issue with my server configs that is causing an issue with domains? I'm not really sure what I need to look at and try to debug this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Flask-Login that was fixed around release 0.2.10 (by me). The bug reappeared in release 0.3.0 of Flask-Login, which as of today is the most current release. I submitted a new fix, plus a unit test to prevent this from ever happening again. The fix was merged a few days ago, but a 0.3.1 release has not been made yet.

Bug report: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/231

My pull request with the fix: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/237

Comment: Hi @Miguel, that seemed to be the issue however, I was actually running version 0.2.11 of Flask-Login. I'm just setting the protection to 'basic' as that appears to be working at the moment. I'll wait for the new release on Pypi and try again using 'strong' to see if your fix resolved the issue for me. Thanks.